# Proof of Ito's isometry on $\lambda^2$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let $\lambda^2$ be the set {$\phi:\phi$ is progressive and E[$\int_0^\infty \phi_s^2ds]< \infty$).

Let $\xi$ the space of simple process.

I know that  the space $\xi$  is dense in ($\lambda^2, || . ||_{\lambda^2} )$.

How could I prove Ito's isometry also for the class of $\lambda^2$ integrands? (I already saw the proof for simple process).

I watched in several book but often they just say that is a direct consequence, without actually proving it.

Comment: No, i mean progressive.

Comment: A integrand have to be progressive for being a well define stochastic integral

Comment: @TimL. I thought progressively measurable processes formed the most general class of integrators?